# Corona SDK: Text coming from sqlite is not wrapping and appearing right on top of other text

Tags: sqlite, coronasdk

I am new to Corona and an am having issues with sqlite and text not wrapping and showing over the top of other text.  The sqlite table is bringing in 3 columns that are name, phone and comment.  The comment column can be very long and is wrapping.  Below is the code I am using.  Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

```
--setting the font size & text display size
local fSize = display.contentWidth * .03
local tTab = display.contentWidth * .05
local tWidth = display.contentWidth * .9
local 

tTop = display.contentHeight * .1


local count =0
local sql = "SELECT * from contacts"
for row i

n db:nrows(sql) do

if row.name == nil then
    print(" NO NAME FOUND!!! ")
end

count = count +1
local dbText = row.name.." - "..row.phone.." - "..row.comment
local t = display.newText(dbText, tTab, tTop + ((fSize * 1.25) + (fSize * 1.25 *        
count)), tWidth, 0, native.systemFont, fSize)
t:setTextColor(255,255,255)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
local ypos= 50
for row in db:nrows(sql) do

if row.name == nil then
 print(" NO NAME FOUND!!! ")
end

count = count +1
local dbText = row.name.." - "..row.phone.." - "..row.comment
local t = display.newText(dbText, tTab, ypos, tWidth, 0, native.systemFont, fSize)
ypos=t.y+ypos+30
t:setTextColor(255,255,255)

end
```